# Compare All Cells in 2 Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to compare every cell in 2 worksheets but the data won't always be in the same row as new data is added and exported constantly.

Range on both sheets would be fairly large, so for now I have limited it to A1:AS150. Any instance where a match cannot be found I'd like to highlight the cell.

I have found this, which looks close to what I need but doesn't work (obviously, I have added the Else code in my working example).

```
Sub test()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

strRangeToCheck = "A1:AS150"
' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
Debug.Print Now

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Cells are identical.
            ' Do nothing.
        Else
            ' Cells are different.
            ' Code goes here for whatever it is you want to do.
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow
```

To answer 'Foxfire And Burns And Burns' Questions:
Checks: Does Sheet1.Cell$.Value exist in sheet2 but for every cell in the range on both sheets.

Sheet1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 999 | ABC111 |
| John | 888 | ABC222 |
| Harry | 777 | ABC333 |
| Tom | 666 | ABC444 |

Sheet2

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 666 | ABC444 |
| John | 888 | ABC222 |
| Harry | 777 | ABC333 |

So in these examples:

Search Sheet1.A1 in Sheet 2, IF = Match Then nothing ELSE Highlight Red. Then A2, A3 etc, Then B1, B2 etc, Then C1, C2 etc...you get the gist.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What kind of check are you doing? Do you need to check if a cell value is present or not? Do you need to compare it to another cell? What kind of result do you expect? What would be a fail?  What would be an exit? Please, post some data example, input and expected out.

Comment: Stating " the data won't always be in the same row as new data is added and exported constantly", the above code cannot return what it looks that you need. It checks cells **for the same positions (row, column)**. If you really need help, you must answer the above questions. If there are some  identic columns arrangement you must state it (in order to save code wasting time) and if some logic in the new added columns/rows/data will also be welcome. Otherwise, it is difficult to be helped if the need is defined only in your head...

Comment: Column positions will always be the same. So, Column A in my examples will ALWAYS be Column A, it's just the rows which will move as new records get added.

Comment: So you want to check if values of Sheet 1 Column A exist in any row of sheet 2 Column A? Then in that case use COUNTIF.

Comment: Should we understand that the rows are not added after the last existing row? Are they added on top of the range? If not, do you like determining only which are the new rows? If not, which is your final goal, please?

Comment: "would be fairly large" - how large ? Is there any one column or combination of columns that is unique to the rows ? Are any columns dates or large text fields ?

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your VBA code that something will need to be done, but in your example your just mean that a cell will be highlighted.

This is already covered by Excel's conditional formatting feature. You can be conditional formatting on a formula (in your case you might use a `Match()` function).

I would advise you to start working with a `=Match()` formula, in order to learn how this works (you might use `=MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$2,0)` as an example, the dollarsigns are used for indicating that the lookup values are not to change), do it on different sheets and then try to get conditional formatting working, first basically and then based on your formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
Dim varSheetA As Worksheet
Dim varSheetB As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long

Set varSheetA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set varSheetB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

LR = varSheetA.Range("A" & varSheetA.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR 'we start at first row of sheet 1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(varSheetB.Range("A:A"), varSheetA.Range("A" & i).Value) = 0 Then varSheetA.Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
Next i

'clean variables

Set varSheetA = Nothing
Set varSheetB = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code will count each single cell value from column A from Sheet 1 and will check if it exists somewhere in column A in Sheet 2. If not, then highligh in red.

Output after executing code with the data example you've posted:

[image]

**UPDATE**": I made a fakedataset. Notice row `Captain America`. Values from columns A and C are same in both sheets, but different on column B

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim varSheetA As Worksheet
Dim varSheetB As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim MyPos As Long

Set varSheetA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set varSheetB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

LR = varSheetA.Range("A" & varSheetA.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR 'we start at first row of sheet 1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(varSheetB.Range("C:C"), varSheetA.Range("C" & i).Value) > 0 Then
        'Match found on Column C. Check A and B
        MyPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(varSheetA.Range("C" & i).Value, varSheetB.Range("C:C"), 0)
        If varSheetA.Range("A" & i).Value <> varSheetB.Range("A" & MyPost.Value Then varSheetA.Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
        If varSheetA.Range("B" & i).Value <> varSheetB.Range("B" & MyPos).Value Then varSheetA.Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next i

'clean variables

Set varSheetA = Nothing
Set varSheetB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

That cell has been highlighet because is different.

Please, note this code will work **only** if all values in column C are **unique**.

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty much exactly what I needed. Is it possible to extend the functionality to say:
Find Sheet1!C1 on Sheet2, when it finds a match to compare all the data from both rows in Sheet 1 & 2? Then loop through the rest of Sheet1!C?

Sorry to ask for changes (getting used to VBA and I'm not 100% sure of what's possible and how to do it)

Comment: You mean to check if cells A,B,C from same row in Sheet 1 exist in any row (but same row) in sheet 2?

Comment: Kinda yes. Using my example tables: Find say Sheet1.C4=ABC444, then Check for that Value in Sheet2.C$ if there is a match compare both Rows and highlight if it any cells don't match. Obviously, the loop would start in C1 but in my example tables this example is in different rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SHEET_1           As String = "Sheet1"
Private Const SHEET_2           As String = "Sheet2"
Private Const FIRST_CELL        As String = "A1"

Private Const MAX_ROWS          As Long = 1048576
Private Const MAX_COLUMNS       As Long = 16384

Private varSheetA               As Worksheet
Private varSheetB               As Worksheet

Private last_row                As Long
Private last_column             As Long
Private sheet1_row              As Long
Private sheet1_column           As Long
Private sheet2_row              As Long

Private row_match               As Boolean


Public Sub CompareTables()

    Set varSheetA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SHEET_1)
    Set varSheetB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SHEET_2)

    'Gets the real Table size
    For sheet1_row = 1 To MAX_ROWS - 1
    
        If varSheetA.Range(FIRST_CELL).Offset(sheet1_row, 0).Value = vbNullString _
                And varSheetB.Range(FIRST_CELL).Offset(sheet1_row, 0).Value = vbNullString Then
        
            last_row = sheet1_row
            Exit For
        
        End If
    
    Next
    For sheet1_column = 1 To MAX_ROWS - 1
    
        If varSheetA.Range(FIRST_CELL).Offset(0, sheet1_column).Value = vbNullString _
                And varSheetB.Range(FIRST_CELL).Offset(0, sheet1_column).Value = vbNullString Then
        
            last_column = sheet1_column
            Exit For
        
        End If
    
    Next
    
    'Sets color RED by default on both Tables
    Call SetTextRed(varSheetA.Range(FIRST_CELL).Resize(last_row, last_column))
    Call SetTextRed(varSheetB.Range(FIRST_CELL).Resize(last_row, last_column))

    'Sweeps all existing ROWS on Sheet1
    For sheet1_row = 1 To last_row
    
        'Sweeps all existing ROWS on Sheet2
        For sheet2_row = 1 To last_row
        
            row_match = True
        
            'Sweeps all existing COLUMNS on Sheet1 and Sheet2
            For sheet1_column = 1 To last_column
            
                If varSheetA.Range(FIRST_CELL).Offset(sheet1_row - 1, sheet1_column - 1).Value _
                        <> varSheetB.Range(FIRST_CELL).Offset(sheet2_row - 1, sheet1_column - 1).Value Then
                
                    row_match = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            
            If row_match Then Exit For 'Found and entire match, no need to search more
            
        Next
        
        'Formats as Grren whenever is a Match
        If row_match Then
        
            Call SetTextGreen(varSheetA.Range(FIRST_CELL).Offset(sheet1_row - 1, 0).Resize(1, last_column))
            Call SetTextGreen(varSheetB.Range(FIRST_CELL).Offset(sheet2_row - 1, 0).Resize(1, last_column))
        
        End If
        
    Next

End Sub


'Sub Function that sets entire row text as RED
Private Sub SetTextRed(ByVal entireRow As Range)

    With entireRow.Font
        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub


'Sub Function that sets entire row text as GREEN
Private Sub SetTextGreen(ByVal entireRow As Range)

    With entireRow.Font
        .Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```